# OpenApi v3: additionalProperties false with referenced schemas

Tags: swagger, jsonschema, openapi

There is some questions around this topic, but I dind't find the right way to do it.

What I want is to define all parameters in a single place and reuse it with no need to write it again. I already get that by using "allOf", but this limited the use of "additionalProperties".

My schema has this structure:

```yaml
SchemaBase:
  type: object
  properties:
    foo:
      type: string

SchemaFull:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaBase'
    - type: object
      properties:
        bar:
          type: string
```

I tried using [using definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787112/swagger-additional-properties-not-allowed-allof) but it seems is not anymore in OpenApi version 3.

[Here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689900/json-schema-allof-with-additionalproperties/#answer-38719753) but its not what I'm looking for, becasue that is for properties, not the entire schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`components`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/) like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: OAS 3
  version: 1.0.0
tags:
- name: example
paths:
  /exe:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              additionalProperties: false
              allOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaBase'
                - type: object
                  properties:
                    bar:
                      type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Foo
          content: {}
components:
  schemas:
    SchemaBase:
      type: object
      properties:
        foo:
          type: string
```

You may see and play with this here: https://editor.swagger.io/

---

JSON schema mapped:

```
{
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/SchemaBase" },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "SchemaBase": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, may be I didn't explain myself. What I want is to use "additionalProperties: false" to validate a union of schemas, but it seems it isn't possible. I already tried with sevaral different combination, but I didn't make it works.

Comment: What validator are you using? - I have added the `additionalProperties: false`, and that is a valid OAS schema

Comment: I'm using express-openapi,  and `additionalProperties: false` works on it, but not along with `allOf`, because only validate one schema or another.

Comment: What I say is that schema won't work, it's syntactically correct, but it will check that none parameters are valid, just because `additionalProperties` work at siblings level, and no enter inside of `allOf`.

Comment: Understood, I have added the corresponding schema and recreated the problem using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/. I will give it a try